# Proper way to format for multiple domains in KRL search annotation

Tags: krl

I am configuring a rule in KRL to annotate based on results of 2+ distinct domains showing in the search results. The first domain works fine, but adding a 2nd or more breaks the rule. Sample of the code I'm using below - is there another way to list these domains?

```js
rule search_annotate_cust is active {
select using "google.com|bing.com/search|search.yahoo.com/search" setting()
every {
  emit <<
    function annotate_cust(toAnnotate, wrapper, data) {
      if (data.domain == "exampleurl.com" ||
         (data.domain == "anotherurl.com" ||
         (data.domain == "sub.exampleurl.com) {
        wrapper.append("<div style='border: 0px solid red'><img  src=http://www.example.com/uploads/product/cust_icon.jpg>");
        wrapper.show();
      }
    }
  >>;
  annotate:annotate("cust") with
    annotator = <| annotate_cust |>;
 }
}
```

Comment: The parentheses in front of the second and third `data.domain` references will cause parse errors. Does removing those solve the problem?

Comment: That did the trick. Seems I should have known that, right? ;-) Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to have a Javascript parser in the IDE so that the code inside an emit gets checked for syntax errors. We take pains to generate correct code, but we can't do anything right now about code inside an emit. For now, whenever a rule just doesn't run, one of the first things to do is to check the browser console for javascript errors.